# Supervisor sometimes stop run on docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, supervisord

I run supervisor on docker container. It starts correctly but after an amount of time it stops schedule jobs and `supervisorctl status` show process are still running.

If I run `supervisorctl status` I had:

```
buildroute-worker:buildroute-worker_00   RUNNING   pid 31348, uptime 6:54:26
gdfexports-worker:gdfexports-worker_00   RUNNING   pid 31267, uptime 6:55:16
```

But this worker are not scheduling

This is my superisord.conf

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

This is my worker conf

```
#nodaemon=false run supervisor in background
[supervisord]
nodaemon=false

[program:gdfexports-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/api/artisan queue:work redis --queue={gdf_exports} --tries=1 --timeout=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/logs/gdfexports-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/tmp/logs/gdfexports-worker-error.log

[program:buildroute-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/api/artisan queue:work redis --queue={build_route} --tries=10 --timeout=60
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/logs/buildroute-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/tmp/logs/buildroute-worker-error.log
```

I start supervisor on a script on CMD dockerfile command

```
supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf &
```

Am I doing some configuration wrong?
Thank you

Comment: A container normally only runs one process in the foreground and then exits.  Can you restructure your application to run each of these parts in separate containers, maybe specifying different commands for each container but using the same image?  Or if not, should `supervisord` be the single foreground process that's the image's `CMD`?

Comment: @DavidMaze supervisor is running in the background. In the foreground is running apache.
I should try to run supervisor in a different container